# TypeScript cast to add extra properties in addition to existing ones

Tags: typescript

If I have an expression, how can I type it to include some extra properties, without repeating existing properties?

E.g. if it is a variable, this seems easy enough (adding field `e`):

```js
const x = { a: 1 };
const y = x as (typeof x) & { e?: number };
```

However what if it's something like this (`x` is nested inside some object):

```js
f({
    x: { a: 1, b: 1, … }
    // I want type of x to be { a: number; b: number; …; e?: number }, 
    // but without repeating all properties
});
```

For the logic it is important not to have `e` in the initial object (even as `undefined`).

But I do need to assign `x.e` later.

Comment: Can `spread` help you? https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/spread-operator/

Comment: @AlexBrohshtut Maybe, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you can use the spread operator for object literals. If your `x` is already declared, it would look something like this:

```
const y = { a: 1, b: 1 }

f({
    x: { ...y, e: 1 }
});
```

Things to note is that anything after `...y` will override existing data if there happens to be `e` in `y` already.